# jQuery onclick does not work

Tags: jquery

I trying to get onclick work, but it does not...
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
    <title>jQuery alert test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            alert('This onclick function forks!');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody tell my, why this onclick does not work?

Comment: Your demo page works on my computer. It alerts just fine.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid It's because the OP corrected the code once they received answers.

Comment: Voting to close since link provided no longer reproduces the issue

Comment: @JoshCrozier - that did cross my mind, but surely they wouldn't be so inconsiderate and careless to go and change a page that people are dedicating their time to look at. Yeah, probably :) Voted to close also.

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to ensure, that his answer works. I reverted the page and added the complete html in the question, so now you can reproduce the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS is being exucuted before the DOM elements have loaded. Your event handler is therefore not being attached to the element since it doesn't exist at the time.

Wrap your JS with a [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        alert('This onclick function forks!');
    });
});
```

---

You could also just use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since the `document` object exists at the time of execution:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {
    alert('This onclick function forks!');
});
```

Comment: I thought it would only be executed, if I click on the button?

Comment: @Zoker But the event listener needs to be attached to the element in order for the function to be executed. If the `#submit` element doesn't exist at execution, then the event handler isn't attached.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe JQuery library is missing..then add this on you code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...code here..
});
```

Comment: If you had checked the OP's link to their demo page, you would see that they have included the jQuery library and have wrapped their code in `document.ready`.

Comment: It's possible that the OP has since updated and fixed his/her page without returning to comment or approve an answer. That's one reason why its best to include code in the question itself, rather than an off-site link. Still, a little more explanation would be helpful in this answer.

Comment: That is a possibilty, but very inconsiderate if it is. Apologies to Sachi if that is the case.

Comment: jQuery was included before, but the document.ready was missing. So that was the problem. I reverted the page back, so you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the document to be ready. You are attempting to attach a click event on something the page does know exists yet.

Fixes range from:

1. moving your the script block to the bottom of the page.
2. or using jQuery's document ready e.g. `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` or `$(function() { ... });`

Of course I'd start with justifying the use of jQuery if all you're using it for is to attach and event listener, but that's just me.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer (using `ready`) works, it's not best practice.

Best practice is to put your `script` tags at the **end** of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag, note the comments below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
    <title>jQuery alert test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
    <!-- NO SCRIPTS HERE -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS GO HERE -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            alert('This onclick function forks!');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That way

1. The elements exist when your code runs
2. Downloading the external scripts doesn't hold up the display of your page

More in the YUI [*Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site*](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).